# Bluetooth transfer is not working on samsung galaxy

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have written code for transferring file using bluetooth in android:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/jokes.txt").toString());
values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION, "0C:71:5D:BA:0E:A8");
values.put(BluetoothShare.TOTAL_BYTES, length);
values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND);
Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);
getContentResolver().insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Its working fine on HTC Desire(Android 4.0) but its not working on samsung galaxy ace(Android 2.3.6). I want this code working on every device.

In Micromax(Android 2.3.4) I am getting error on last line as follows,

```
Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.android.bluetooth.opp/btopp
```

Any Idea?

Comment: @Dhanush Have you found the Solution for this problem..please post the complete code,..it would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try to send it be either way as follows,

```
File file = new File ( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/jokes.txt" );
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
values.put( BluetoothShare.URI, Uri.fromFile( file ).toString() );
values.put( BluetoothShare.DESTINATION, "0C:71:5D:BA:0E:A8" );
values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND);
Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);
getContentResolver().insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: I tried my code on Micromax(Android 2.3.4) and it gives exception:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.android.bluetooth.opp/btopp

Comment: /sdcard/ is not accessable in all android device, hence you need to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, i have updated my answer, try it now.

Comment: ok one more advice, instead of passing static bt-address, try first fetching bt-address and pass that one, sometimes it happens that last two digits of bt-address get changed as per the device's os & structure.

Comment: @Lucifer how does this work..shall i have to push Content values object to Remote Socket or it will automatically be pushed? Will it prompt the user to Accept or reject the file.  It would be helpful if you post the complete Code...Thanks in advance.